# Prevent users from registering twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a register form and I want to check that the user did not register before.

My code is in below. I think two problems exist: (1) the call method and (2) passing the parameter to the stored procedure. My symptom is that this causes an exception that says the input parameter not initialized.

```
create procedure fakeuser @username nvarchar(250),@codemeli nchar(10),@email     nvarchar(50), @user nvarchar(250) output,@code nchar(10)output,@mail nvarchar(50)output
 as
if exists(select username,email,codemeli from karbar where username=@username)
set @user=@username
else if exists(select username,email,codemeli from karbar where codemeli=@codemeli)
set @code=@codemeli
else if exists(select username,email,codemeli from karbar where email=@email)
set @mail= @email
```

Here is the c# code:

```
  public static string confirm(string username, string email, string codemeli)
    {
        string constring = "data source=.;database=site;integrated security=true;";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring);

        // Command - specify as StoredProcedure
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("fakeuser", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = username;
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param2.Value = username;
        command.Parameters.Add(param2);

        SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@codemeli", SqlDbType.NChar);
        param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param3.Value = username;
        command.Parameters.Add(param3);

        // Return value as parameter
        SqlParameter returnuser = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        returnuser.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(returnuser);

        SqlParameter returncode = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.NChar);

        returncode.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        command.Parameters.Add(returncode);
        SqlParameter returnmail = new SqlParameter("@mail", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        returnmail.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        command.Parameters.Add(returnmail);

        // Execute the stored procedure
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  You need to use your Visual Studio debugger, SQL Server Management Studio, and other programming tools to figure out what part of the code is causing the problem.  We are happy to help if you find the problem and can't figure out how to fix it, but I think you'll find most people won't want to find your problem for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ParameterDirection=Output` for @user,@code, and @mail and also specify the width/size/length of parameter.

```
 SqlParameter returnuser = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100);
 returnuser.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 command.Parameters.Add(returnuser);
```

Comment: i do it but this exception occur-> the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: @quantum62 - you have to specify the **length** of output parameter.